# Completeness of $L^{2}([-a,a])$

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

I'm reading Nadir Jeevanjee's *An Introduction to Tensors and Group Theory for Physicists* (2ed). In it, he says the following:

> For $L^{2}([-a,a])$ for which $\{e^{i\frac{n \pi x}{a}}\}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ is an orthonormal basis, ... any $f\in L^{2}([-a,a])$ can be written as
>   \begin{equation}
> f=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_{n}e^{i\frac{n \pi x}{a}} \qquad (2.37)
> \end{equation}
>   where
>   \begin{equation}
> \frac{1}{2a}\int\limits_{-a}^{a} |f|^2 dx = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty |c_{n}|^2 < \infty \qquad (2.38)
> \end{equation}
>   The converse to this is also true, and this is where the completeness of $L^{2}([-a,a])$ is essential: if a set of numbers $c_n$ satisfy $(2.38)$, then the series
>   \begin{equation}
> g(x)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_{n}e^{i\frac{n \pi x}{a}} \qquad (2.39)
> \end{equation}
>   converges, yielding a square-integrable function $g$.

I don't understand why if a set of numbers $c_n$ satisfy $(2.38)$, then g converges. Can someone please explain why?

(I suppose that if it converges, then by the completeness of $L^2$, we can say that it converges to an element of $L^2$.)

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $v_n$ is some sequence of orthonormal vectors indexed by a set $U$ in a Hilbert space (a complete inner product space) and $\sum_{n\in U} |c_n|^2 < \infty$ then
$$\sum_{n\in U} c_nv_n$$
converges.

Exactly how you prove this depends a bit on how you defined an infinite sum, but the basic idea stays the same: Suppose that you have some finite set of indices $I$ and some larger finite set $I'$. Define
$$S_I=\sum_{n\in I}c_nv_n$$
$$S_{I'}=\sum_{n\in I'}c_nv_n.$$
Let's figure out how far apart $S_I$ and $S_{I'}$ are - note that
$$S_{I'}-S_{I}=\sum_{n\in I'\setminus I}c_nv_n.$$
If you take the inner product of this (finite) sum with itself, you note that $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle = 0$ if $i\neq j$ and $1$ otherwise by the hypothesis of orthonormality. Thus
$$\|S_{I'}-S_{I}\|^2 = \sum_{n\in I'\setminus I}|c_n|^2 \leq \sum_{n\in U\setminus I}|c_n|^2.$$
However, the fact that $\sum_{n\in U}|c_n|^2 < \infty$ implies that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is a finite set $I$ such that $\sum_{n\in U\setminus I}|c_n|^2 < \varepsilon$ - meaning that the "tail" of the sum is small. In particular, if we set $\varepsilon = \alpha^2$, we would conclude that there is some finite set $I$ such that for every finite $I'$ containing $I$ we get
$$\|S_{I'}-S_I\| < \alpha.$$
In the unlikely event that you are working with nets to define sums, this is exactly what Cauchy means; in the more likely even that you mean
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_nv_n = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=-N}^Nc_nv_n$$
the same fact implies that there is some $N$ such that if $N_1,N_2$ are greater than $N$ then
$$\left\|\sum_{n=-N_1}^{N_1}c_nv_n - \sum_{n=-N_2}^{N_2}c_nv_n\right\| < 2\alpha$$
which implies that the sequence of values $\sum_{n=-N}^Nc_nv_n$ is a Cauchy sequence and hence converges.

Comment: Can you please explain the last step in more detail. I don't get it. Thanks in advance.

And yes, the infinite sum was defined earlier in the book as 
\begin{equation}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} c^{i}v_{i} = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} c^{i}v_{i}.\end{equation}

Comment: @Viswa Could you be more specific about which step you don't get? I'm not sure what constitutes the "last step"?

Comment: The one with the '$2\alpha$'.